# unable to acess $_GET when dynamically loaded

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm not sure what is the problem here.

I am using a plugin in wordpress that displays a popup for the users to sign up to the mailing list.

In this plugin, I want to be able to add a variable in a hidden field to post along so I can tell if the user has come from a specific affiliate campaign.

In the url I have

```
http://example.com/?urlref=affname
```

and in the modal window that pops up I have coded:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['urlref'])) { ?>
     // do stuff here
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>No Aff Link</p>
<?php } ?>
```

and what i am getting returned is **No Aff Link**

I have tried using

```
$_REQUEST['urlref']
```

but that does not work either.

I have added the above code into the site page (not in the popup) and it works. So it's something to do with it being dynamically loaded I think.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which plugin have you used ?

Comment: How does your code open up the modal window?

Comment: The code is a form with elements. Where the hidden field that I want to show up should be, there is this: <p>No Aff Link</p>

Comment: `<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>` can you put that in pop up and tell me the output of it ? Does it have **http://example.com/?urlref=affname** ?

Comment: Yes; http://localhost:8888/?urlref=affiliate1

Comment: That is the reason why it is opening in **Site Page** and not opening in Pop up because in pop up it might be making some request. So now you need to modify your if condition and your condition can be with `strpos` function of php,

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner - can you give me an example? I'm getting a warning: strpos requires two parameters etc....

Comment: @MarkP Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to the answer :

Reason for `$_GET['urlref']` not accessible in pop up might be an request which change the **URL** as well as `$_GET`. so you will able to access `$_GET['urlref']` in **Site Page** but not in pop up.

So you can change your `if` condition in popup like below :

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (strpos($url,'urlref') !== false) {
    echo 'urlref exists.';
} else {
    echo 'No urlref.';
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thank you, Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load your `affiliate` variable dynamically then you need to store this variable in `session` or `cookie`:

You just need to `set session` in your site page:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(isset($_GET['urlref'])) { 
    $_SESSION['urlref'] = $_GET['urlref'];
} else { 
    $_SESSION['urlref'] = '';
} 
?>
```

Now you can get this `$_SESSION['urlref']` in you model page as well through `session`.

Comment: This didnt work. Still getting the else block output

Comment: Did you start `session` on your model page as well?

Comment: Session was started in the functions.php - Will add to the plugin page also and see.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the hidden field that you want to add is not in the `<form>` tag, so that it is not sent to the server. Need more details with your problems (what's plugin, HTML code,...)